# Python's os.listdir() with os.path.isdir() does not return all directories

Tags: python

I'm traversing a directory tree (upwards) and I need to find all directories. However the output of [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir), when combined with [`os.path.isdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.isdir#os.path.isdir) is not what I would expect.

For example, this only shows two directories (`bin` and `dev`):

```
    $ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> for d in os.listdir('/'):
...  if os.path.isdir(d):
...   print d
... 
bin
dev
>>>
```

However, removing the `os.path.isdir()` call lists all entries, both files and directories:

```
>>> for d in os.listdir('/'):
...  print d
... 
sbin
home
initrd.img
[...]
run
sys
>>>
```

The surprising bit is that running `isdir` on a directory that is **not** listed by the first snippet returns True:

```
>>> os.path.isdir('/run')
True
>>>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `os.path.isdir` is checking if the directory exists under the *current* directory, not the directory that `os.listdir` is listing (`'/'`).

Try this:

```
for d in os.listdir('/'):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('/', d)):
        print d
```